# How to Reap data from a ScheduledTask?

Tags: functions, evaluation, scheduling

Here is an amusing little function mapped over a range just to iterate it. It ignores its argument and works entirely by side-effecting a global variable:

```
n$ = 1;
Map[(n$ = (n$++) + n$) &, Range[5]]
```

> ```
> {3, 7, 15, 31, 63}
> ```

Here is a version of the same thing, just using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
n$ = 1;
Reap[Map[Sow[n$ = (n$++) + n$] &, Range[5]]][[1]]
```

> ```
> {3, 7, 15, 31, 63}
> ```

Here is a version that evaluates the function in an asynchronous task, capturing the result in a `Dynamic` (you'll have to key it in to a notebook, or evaluate the [SEUploader (courtesy of @halirutan)](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools) notebook I linked at the end of this post, to see the variable `n$` updating dynamically):

```
n$ = 1;
Dynamic[n$]
RunScheduledTask[n$ = (n$++) + n$, {0.25, 5}];
```

> ```
> 63
> ```

Clean up the task:

```
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]]
```

Now, here is an attempt to *also* capture the results in a `Reap` (notice no semicolon at the end; I want to see the results of the `Reap` as well as to see the `Dynamic`):

```
n$ = 1;
Dynamic[n$]
Reap[RunScheduledTask[Sow[n$ = (n$++) + n$], {0.25, 5}]]
```

> ```
> 63
>
> {ScheduledTaskObject[7, HoldForm[Sow[n$ = Increment[n$] + n$]], {0.25, 5}, 
> Automatic, True, "AutoRemove" -> False, "EpilogFunction" :> Null, 
> "TaskGroup" -> "Global`"], {}}
> ```

and its cleanup

```
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]]
```

Evidently, the `Reap` is evaluated too early and the sown results are lost. How can I get the intended results?

Here's the entire notebook, SE-Uploaded (just evaluate the following expression in a fresh notebook):

```
Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1zYS.png"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this that way,

when you evaluate `RunScheduledTask` you are only sending a held procedure for scheduled evaluation to Kernel. But `Reap[expr]`:

> gives the value of *expr* together with all expressions to which **`Sow` has been applied during its evaluation**.

`RunScheduledTask` is of course `HoldFirst` so `Sow` is not applied at this time.

You can put `Reap` inside but the you will need also some temporary variable to be able to retrive reaped value from scheduled evaluation.